# MVC areas to have their own url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible to have MVC areas that are referenced by domain name in IIS? For example

/Areas/Area1

/Areas/Area2

URLs:

http://area1.mydomain.com

http://area2.myotherdomain.com

Both of these domains point to the same folder on the server but get the different areas within the folder.

Thanks

Comment: This is known as multi-tenant routing.  There is no built-in support for this, but there are various things you can do to achieve it.  Just knowing the term "multi-tenant" and MVC should help you a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to map subdomains to areas in MVC? It is not clear whether you are looking at how to do this in your code or on IIS? Below is a link to an article I used to contstruct c# code to handle this:

http://tech.opentable.co.uk/blog/2013/09/25/resolving-domains-to-areas-in-asp-dot-net-mvc/